# How to break a python list tuple into tuple with two elements?

Tags: python, list, split, tuples

I have a list and want to split each elements into a tuple of two elements.

The list looks like:

```
 list_doctors = ['dr.naman_5','dr.akanksha_7','dr.sumant_3']
```

How do I create a list of the form:

```
modified_list = [('dr.naman','5'),('dr.akanksha','7'),('dr.sumant','3')]
```

Comment: Can you please share what you've tried so far? Even if it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Try the following.

```
>>> list_doctors = ['dr.naman_5','dr.akanksha_7','dr.sumant_3']
>>> [tuple(s.split('_')) for s in list_doctors]
[('dr.naman', '5'), ('dr.akanksha', '7'), ('dr.sumant', '3')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `split()`.

```
>>> list_doctors = ['dr.naman_5','dr.akanksha_7','dr.sumant_3']
>>> modified_list = [item.split('_') for item in list_doctors]
>>> modified_list
[['dr.naman', '5'], ['dr.akanksha', '7'], ['dr.sumant', '3']]
```